# Arrows from GraphicsComplex not converted to Normal form correctly

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, bugs, conversion

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.1**

---

```
Show @ Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, Frame -> True]
Normal @ %
```

[image]

Is this a pure bug, or have I missed something?

---

`InputForms` reveal that `Disks` are converted correctly while `Arrows` remain in `GraphicsComplex` form. Going with investigation further, I found that not all `Arrows`...

```
{#, Normal @ #} & @ Graphics[
    GraphicsComplex[
      {{0, 0}, {1., 0}, {2., 0}}, 
      {
        {Thickness@.05, Blue, Arrow[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, .03]},
        {Thickness@.01, Red, Arrow[{1, 2}, .03], Arrow[{2, 3}, .03]}
    }], 
    ImageSize -> 300
]
```

[image]

So, as we can see, "separate" arrows are converted correctly while those gathered under one `Arrow` are not...

**Q** is there any quick fix to convert `Graph` to normal form correctly?

V10.3.1 Win 10

Comment: `Normal[# /. a : Arrow[{__List}, _] :> Thread@a]` gives a quick fix for these examples

Comment: Now answered ;-)

Comment: I don't see how this can be anything but a bug so I am adding the tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Normal[# /. a : Arrow[{__List}, Except[_List]] :> Thread @ a]
```

gives a quick fix for these examples.

Comment: I'd add `Except[_List]` for the second argument since it can be a list too. Or better map with it.

Comment: @Kuba, good point